# Can't assign value in Java 2D Array - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm having trouble assigning a value to my 2D array in Java. The last line of the code, `theGrid[rowLoop][colLoop] = 'x';`, is throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error. Could someone please explain why this is happening?

This is my code...

```
public class Main {
    public static char[][] theGrid;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createAndFillGrid(10,10);
    }

    public static void createAndFillGrid(int rows, int cols) {
        theGrid = new char[rows][cols];
        int rowLoop = 0;

        for (rowLoop = 0; rowLoop <= theGrid.length; rowLoop++) {
            int colLoop = 0;

            for (colLoop = 0; colLoop <= theGrid[0].length; colLoop++) {
                theGrid[rowLoop][colLoop] = 'x';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the problem `rowLoop <= theGrid.length` and `colLoop <= theGrid[0].length`.  It should be:

```
rowLoop < theGrid.length
```

and

```
colLoop < theGrid[0].length
```

The reason for the error is because your index is going up to the length of the array.  So, if the length were 10, you go up to index 10.  This is not a valid index into the array.  Arrays have valid indices from `0` to `length - 1`.

Comment: That was an incredibly fast answer! And it works thank you so much!

Comment: @marsh, glad to help.  Don't forget to accept this answer once the system lets you.